# Is it okay to give an answer which just provides a link to another post on SO

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

I was reviewing the Low Quality Posts and I encountered an answer which just gives a link to another answer on Stack Overflow. I hit the Recommend Deletion because it is a link only answer. But it was an audit and it had many upvotes as well, so I failed the audit.

This is the [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/7804428).

And this is the answer

> Looks like they removed the underscore from the generated stuff.  See [Dagger2 generated class is all of a sudden missing from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509014/dagger2-generated-class-is-all-of-a-sudden-missing-from-android-studio).

Now, **I want to ask if such an answer is okay, that is an answer that just gives a link to another post on Stack Overflow**. Normally, such posts should be a comment, so I decided to Recommend Deletion. But that answer seems to have a lot of up votes.

So, was what I did wrong?
Should I have instead hit Looks Ok?

Please lend me some knowledge on how such posts should be treated.

Comment: Thanks, I had missed that post. After reading it, I decided to flag it as a Dupe. But I'm still wondering why that answer recieved so many upvotes?

Comment: I'd probably have done the same as you. That's a comment, not an answer, and should have been a flag as a duplicate rather than a link.

Comment: @ArunA.S: Sometimes, one is simply left wondering... which is one of the reasons review-audits won't ever all be correct.

Comment: @Deduplicator , so shouldn't that post be removed from the audit? Anyone would have failed on that one.

Comment: It already stopped being an audit: I gifted a downvote, as did someone else. Aside from that, I dupe-voted the question and flagged the answer.

Comment: @Deduplicator , thanks for that. BTW I was the other downvoter. I just wanted to make sure that it would be the right thing to do, so I waited for some reply before downvoting.